# Android - Sign-in with multiple social networks

Tags: java, android, authentication, mobile

Implementing multiple sign-in methods in my Android app (G+ , Facebook , LinkedIn). I'm trying to select the best approach for the design.

- 3 Services that handles each social network

or

- 1 Super class that defines the common methods and 3 classes that extends it and implements the specific login internal

Any other approach, code reference or any other input would be welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library just for this purpose. It supports Twitter, FB, LinkedIn and Google+.
https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks

Comment: It seems that it is still under development, is there a more mature library you know of?

Comment: A quick google gave me following results. https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/
http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-Android-social-networks-library
and https://github.com/sdossick/SocialLib
They are all more or less matured. But since social networks are self under permanent developement there can`t be an all time solution i`m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

try this library 
https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE
it works for google, twitter facebook...

Comment: Please provide some content from the link.

Comment: You have an example link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815900/Android-social-network-integration and the code https://github.com/gorbin/ASNETutorial